# Specify interactive rendering mode for asymptotes RPC/PDF export

Tags: pdf, asymptote

I started using asymptote for some 3D graphics lately which works quite nice. For example I have a set of points on the sphere (where i put just e few of them into this example file) like

```
import settings;
import three;
import solids;unitsize(4cm);

currentprojection=perspective( camera=(1,.4,.9), target = (0,0,0));
currentlight=nolight;

revolution S=sphere(O,1);
draw(surface(S),surfacepen=lightgrey+opacity(.6),meshpen=0.6*white+linewidth(.5pt));
pen LineStyle1 = rgb(0.3,0.3,1)+linewidth(1.5pt)+opacity(1);
dot((1,0,0),LineStyle1);
dot((0.99992,0.012295,0.00023746),LineStyle1);
dot((0.9997,0.024582,0.00094946),LineStyle1);
dot((0.99932,0.036854,0.002135),LineStyle1);
dot((0.99879,0.049104,0.0037921),LineStyle1);
dot((0.9981,0.061324,0.0059185),LineStyle1);
dot((0.99726,0.073506,0.0085108),LineStyle1);
dot((0.99626,0.085643,0.011565),LineStyle1);
dot((0.9951,0.097727,0.015077),LineStyle1);
dot((0.99378,0.10975,0.019041),LineStyle1);
dot((0.99229,0.1217,0.023452),LineStyle1);
```

which looks rendered as png (`asy -f png -render 3 myfile.asy`) like

[image: Sphere points png]

However, I would like to demonstrate how the whole set of points looks on all the sphere (say in a talk) interactively, therefore i am generating the PDF with included RPC by calling
`asy -f pdf myfile.asy`

which (opened in Acrobat reader) activates the interactive mode when i click on that. However during drags it looks like

[image: Sphere points during interaction]

And even after that a tesselation is visible disturbing the beauty of my scene.

What do I have to do with my example such that the second operation (i.e. interactively playing around with the sphere) the sphere still looks at least something like the rendered PNG? Are there some prc settings for that? I couldn't find any in the manual.

**Edit:** @Charles Staats remarks were a first great step. Setting `defaultrender.merge = true;`and `defaultrender.compression=Low;` i noticed, that for the interactive view `currentlight=Viewport;` is better and ended up with

[image: updated interactive view]

Which looks nearly fine, just that in the interactive view (`asy -V` just for comparison), the transparency is handled far better (though using `nolight`again). How can I improve that in the PDF? I only could get a result changing the lighning to „helle Beleuchtung“ (bright ligthning) manually in Adobe and would like to specify that in the source code, too.

Comment: Have you tried the `-V option` for interactive 3d viewing?

Comment: @g.kov In the interactive 3D viewing it looks really fine. But I want a PDF so that I can include an interactive graphic in my Talk. And yes, it should behave just like the interactive mode :)

Comment: First, make sure you are using an up-to-date version of Adobe Reader. (I'm serious here; at least on a Mac, there has been a drastic shift in prc rendering in the ~3 years I've been using Asymptote.) In addition to that, try putting the line `defaultrender.merge = true;` right after `import three;`. You might also try adding `defaultrender.compression = Low;`, although I have no idea if that will have the effect you are looking for.

Comment: @Charles Staats Thanks, your comment improved the result by far ;) Yes, I am already using the newest version of Adobe Reader on my Mac. Nevertheless there's a little error left, see my updated question.

Comment: Transparency in 3d rendering is broken; if you tried compiling the `asy -V` version with `currentlight=Viewport`, you'd see the same artifacts. However, in your case, you can get rid of these issues in prc mode by setting `defaultrender.closed=true`. You can also improve the static image by compiling with `-render 0` rather than `-render 3`, although this means that objects drawn later will show up on top even when they should not.

Comment: Your ideas work fine for the MWE I posted, so If you would like to expand that into an answer, I would be happy to accept that. Nevertheless, when I increase the number of points (to form two sampled curves having 500 dots each), they again switch back to a (though more detailed than in the screenshot) wireframe model.